# Can i work with ESP32- Dev kit and ESP32-WebCam in a Sender and receiver interface?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32, esp8266wifi

I'm new in working with embedded programming and I've got a question that is - "I would like to make a project where if I press a button it should send a 15 seconds video to the contact number mentioned in the program (which I've yet to make. I was saying this because i wanted to explain my project). So, I'm using ESP32-Web Cam for capturing the video and send it through Wi-Fi".

I'm using Arduino IDE 2.0.4 to upload my code.

Now the problem I'm currently facing is that:

1. Which board should I choose in Arduino IDE to upload the program (i.e., either in ESP32 Dev kit (My main uC) ?
2. I don't know how should i make code compatible to both the ESP32 and ESP32-WebCam.

If anyone has ideas about this please help me it'd be helpful and I'd be thankful.

Thank you.

I'm using ESP32 Dev kit to upload my code in ESP32-WebCam (I'm not using FTDI cable)

I tried to make the example code **ESP32 example--> Camera--> CameraWebServer** with my main code as i tried importing as an H file and used the functions in my main function but it showed the following errors:

My files are arranged in the following manner:
Main program

- main.ino
- app_httpd.cpp
- camera_index.h
- camera_pins.h
- esp32_webCam.h

Here, I've included the files given by the ESP32-Examples.

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHT11PIN 16
#define LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN 36
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "esp32_webCam.h"   //This is the CameraWebServer file that i'm including in the main file
```

The error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4/tools/sdk/esp32/include/esp32-camera/driver/include/esp_camera.h:71,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:1,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:11:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4/tools/sdk/esp32/include/esp32-camera/driver/include/sensor.h:201:24: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct _sensor sensor_t'
 typedef struct _sensor sensor_t;
                        ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MPU6050/Adafruit_MPU6050.h:23,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:4:
c:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Unified_Sensor/Adafruit_Sensor.h:157:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct sensor_t sensor_t'
 } sensor_t;
   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4/tools/sdk/esp32/include/esp32-camera/driver/include/esp_camera.h:71,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:1,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:11:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4/tools/sdk/esp32/include/esp32-camera/driver/include/sensor.h:249:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct _sensor sensor_t'
 } sensor_t;
   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\Users\Emb Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MPU6050/Adafruit_MPU6050.h:23,
                 from G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:4:
c:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Unified_Sensor/Adafruit_Sensor.h:157:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct sensor_t sensor_t'
 } sensor_t;
   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:11:
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h: In function 'void cam_setup()':
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:108:10: error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'id'
   if (s->id.PID == OV3660_PID) {
          ^~
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:109:8: error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'set_vflip'
     s->set_vflip(s, 1); // flip it back
        ^~~~~~~~~
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:110:8: error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'set_brightness'
     s->set_brightness(s, 1); // up the brightness just a bit
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:111:8: error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'set_saturation'; did you mean 'resolution'?
     s->set_saturation(s, -2); // lower the saturation
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        resolution
G:\All_Program\all_program\esp32_webCam.h:115:8: error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'set_framesize'
     s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino: In function 'void pulsesensor()':
G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:72:19: error: 'LED_BUILTIN' was not declared in this scope
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:76:19: error: 'LED_BUILTIN' was not declared in this scope
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino: In function 'void setup()':
G:\All_Program\all_program\all_program.ino:283:11: error: 'LED_BUILTIN' was not declared in this scope
   pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'struct sensor_t' has no member named 'id'
```